# How to install strophe for use with a browser

Tags: javascript, browser, strophe

I am trying to use Strophe.js (https://github.com/strophe/strophejs) to create a browser-based XMPP client. However, the documentation doesn't explain how to get it set up and running and the examples provided in the GitHub do not run in a browser.
How do I install strophe.js for use with a browser, or what steps should I take to use it in a javascript application that is not using node.js?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for documentation in github project repo which may or may not necessarily contain the documentation. The correct link for the documentation can be found in the [project homepage](https://strophe.im/strophejs/) (link is provided in the repo) as well as the link to the [latest documentation](https://strophe.im/strophejs/doc/1.4.3/files/strophe-umd-js.html) (which is also provided in the project repo). Few examples are also included as part of the project repo ( https://github.com/strophe/strophejs/tree/master/examples)

Comment: The documentation at those links does not have any information on actually installing and running Strophe.js, just the documentation for individual functions and variables. As I said in the question, the examples provided in GitHub will not actually run in a browser.

Comment: What do you mean by installing? Are you referring to building a custom Strophe version? Otherwise you just need to include StropheJS in your web page and initialise it. For complete reference the link to the book is also provided, Since Strophe implements XMPP Extensions (XEPs), https://github.com/strophe/strophejs-plugins is a good place to start for implementations of XEPs using Strophe. Other than this, there are open source XMPP clients like https://github.com/conversejs/converse.js that use Strophe (For your reference).